# Warning message when extract months from chron object

Tags: r, lubridate, chron

I'm maintaining some code that uses both the lubridate and chron packages and a new warning has cropped up.

*Warning message:
tz(): Don't know how to compute timezone for object of class dates/times; returning "UTC". This warning will become an error in the next major version of lubridate.*

This arises when extracting months from an object made by chron.

```
library(lubridate)
library(chron)
xdate <- structure(c(23831, 23832, 23833, 23834, 23835, 23836), 
         format = "d/m/y", origin = c(month = 1, day = 1, year = 1900), class = c("dates", "times"))


lubridate::month(xdate)
```

I can get around this by wrapping xdate in as.Date
`lubridate::month(as.Date(xdate))`.  The dates produced are correct.  Is this approach ok?

Edit:  I see another way of getting around this is `chron::month.day.year(xdate)$month`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that would be ok but to avoid problems it might be better not to use lubridate for this.  chron has `months` and `monday.day.year` and we provide some other conversions as well:

```
as.integer(months(xdate))  # uses chron:::months.default
## [1] 4 4 4 4 4 4

c(months(xdate))
## [1] 4 4 4 4 4 4

month.day.year(xdate)$month # uses chron::month.day.year
## [1] 4 4 4 4 4 4

as.integer(format(as.Date(xdate), "%m"))
## [1] 4 4 4 4 4 4

library(zoo)
cycle(as.yearmon(xdate))
## [1] 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: I find I am getting incorrect results when I use "months(xdate)" or "month.day.year(xdate)" (after loading the chron library), but I get correct results when I explicitly use "chron:::months.default(xdate)". Any idea why? I don't use the default "m/d/y" format and this sometimes seems to cause issues.

Comment: @Barbara, Perhaps there are multiple packages defining `months.default` loaded?  See what `getAnywhere("months.default")` returns.  Also try it with a fresh instance of R and no other packages loaded -- just chron.